# How to make daily schedule push local notification using React Native?

Tags: react-native

We would like to get notification every morning at 7:00am.
We try to use **zo0r/react-native-push-notification** but We don't know to make it push local notification daily everyday with specific time. We want it to work both on ios and android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cron-job

## Api

If you are using an API for your application then you can store the tokens of the mobile phones that you are gonna send notifications in your database and can initiate the process of sending notification bu using a API call on the time using node cron or cron which can be used to schedule things.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

## if not

If you are not using any apis you can schedule the notifications from your app itself by using  react native cron.
This helps to run a task on a particular time.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cron-job